# How do you tell if a quest/mission is completed?

Tags: pc, mass-effect-3

For the Hanar Diplomat mission, I do not remember completing it. But it is marked grey (typically when complete).

I have now finished the Citadel story mission where you

> save the Citadel from attack

Why is this mission grey like I already completed it? Can I

> still get Kasumi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get Kasumi as a squad member, only a war asset, as far as I know. Grey missions are considered completed, orange ones are not yet completed. It is unlikely you will be able to restart a mission that has been marked for completed.

Quests may be marked as completed (grey) if they are no longer possible to complete.

Comment: So do quests get marked "completed" by other means?

Comment: I don't think I've experienced that behavior, but I don't see why they wouldn't. If a quest becomes impossible to complete, it shouldn't be active.

Comment: I have had firsthand experience with quests being marked completed after they become impossible to complete. Editing the answer to reflect that.